# npm pack removing file extensions from import

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, ecmascript-5, npm-pack

I'm trying to a create an internal library for work.

All seems to be fine until I attempt to use in another project.
The file extension in all of the `import` statements seems to have been removed during the `npm pack` phase.

In other words, the statement:

`import * as Account from './modules/account.js'`

becomes:

`import * as Account from './modules/account'`

This causes the import to fail.

I originally thought this may have been because I used the `.js` extension instead of `.mjs`, but switching to `.mjs` yields the same results.

**main.js**

```
import * as Account from './modules/account.js'

Account.secretSquirrel().then( data => console.log( 'inspector gadget', data ) );
```

**node version**

`v16.15.0`

**package.json** (sensitive info redacted)

```
{
  "name": "@Nunya",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Nunya",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./lib/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run pack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "Nunya.git"
  },
  "author": "Nunya",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./lib/main.js",
      "default": "./lib/main.js"
    },
    "./Account": "./lib/modules/account.js"
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this shouldn't be happening. Not sure how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, adding an `import` object defining the resolutions for the relative paths to `package.json` resolves this issue. Although, I'm certain there's a non-manual way to accomplish this, it is unbeknownst to me at this time.

If anyone knows, please let me know